# /tour and /about are duplicates of the same page

Tags: discussion, tour, redirection

Is there any reason why https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/about are duplicate pages instead of having a 301 redirect?

I would assume that /about would redirect to /tour, but they're the two separate versions of the same page by all accounts. The same is true on all Stack Exchange sites too. 
Shouldn't they be 301 to avoid having duplicate pages?

That's probably not a problem for StackOverflow, but for the smaller Stack Exchange sites (and the beta ones) having duplicate pages like this is (allegedly) something that search engines penalize sites for, so it's *possible* that the smaller sites are losing out on some incoming traffic as a result.

Comment: Note: It looks like `/about` has since been changed to redirect to `/tour`, as you assumed it would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out.

We are currently using this page for two different reasons, so it doesn't bother me all that much that they have the same URL. We will probably standardize in the future, but we are still trying to figure out what the best language to use for new users is.

I wouldn't worry about the SEO hit. It's just one page among thousands.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a test. You get the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge for reading the entire *About* page, but not for reading the entire *Tour*.